# Android: ListView item deselected after tap

Tags: android, events, listview, layout, click

I have a ListView with a pretty standard view for each row - an icon with two labels (source below). I can use the keyboard to select items (which stay selected), but if I tap an item it's selected then deselected. Should it not stay selected? I've tried overriding the onKeyDown and onListItemClick events and just returning super.onKeyDown, but then the app just hangs.

The source of each row is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:minWidth="24px"
                       android:maxWidth="24px"
                       android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
                android:textSize="18dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
           android:textSize="12dip"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A item of a ListView doesn't stay selected when you touch it. The selection is only there for you to see, where your selection is when you use a keyboard/touchball.

Take a look in the ListViews of the settings (telefon info) there you can click on items and they don't stay selected...

Comment: So why would the application just hang if I override the onKeyDown and onListItemClick events?

Comment: You just have the super calls inside? Than you should check if the app really hangs inside...

Comment: It looks like overriding both onListItemClick and onKeyDown was causing it to hang. I needed to do super.onListItemClick, then use the id to fire my method.